# Jasper Dynamic reports website

Tags: dynamic-reports

I’m currently using the library [Dynamic Reports](http://www.dynamicreports.org/) that uses Jasper Reports, but it seems the website is out of service now.

Will it be fixed soon ? Is the library still working ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: At the moment of writing this comment, I found the documentation here @ https://dynamicreports.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and the git repository can be found @ https://github.com/dynamicreports/dynamicreports

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what happened to the project but it also disappeared from SourceForge (https://sourceforge.net/p/dynamicreports/).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the project is now on GIT
https://github.com/dynamicreports 

Documentation and examples is still missing though

Answer (score 0):

Pursuant to the failure of that website, the project was cloned by some users, from existing files and ported over to github. The documentation is still work in progress, as it seems that it has to be reconstituted from the ground up. The continuing work can be accessed at https://dynamicreports.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.
By the way, the original artifacts can still be downloaded from maven central and the library at least up to version 5.1.0. As for continuing support and maintenance, it's a matter of time, but these contributors contributors intend to see to it that this library flourishes.